# Как на линейной диаграмме изменить тип линии на пунктирную?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Есть линейная диаграмма. Линия показателя прописана примерно так

```
series: [{
      type: 'line',
      style: {
           stroke: '#30BDA7',
           lineWidth: 2
      },
      xField: 'name',
      yField: 'data1'
}]
```

Подскажите, есть ли вообще возможность выводить не сплошную линию, а допустим пунктирную?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос более не актуален.

Тип линии изменяется в свойстве style:

`series: [{ 
type: 'line', 
style: { 
   'stroke-width': 3, //- ширина строки
   'stroke-dasharray': '10' //- делает пунктирную линию
   'stroke-dasharray': '10 5 1 5' //- делает штрихпунктирную линию
}, 
xField: 'name', 
yField: 'data1' 
}]`

Comment: Если вы используете Extjs графики, то вместо 'stroke-dasharray' используйте lineDash:

`lineDash: [10], //-делает пунктирную линию.
lineDash: [10,5,2,5] //-делает штрихпунктирную линию`